# Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView'

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, uwp

I Have an UWP app with two xaml renders this one named **SongFix.xaml** (estándar view)

```
<Page
        x:Class="Tablaturas.Views.SongFix"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:local="using:Tablaturas.Views"
        xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
        xmlns:cvt="using:Tablaturas.Code"
        xmlns:ctr="using:Tablaturas.Controls"
        xmlns:data="using:Tablaturas.Model"    
        xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
        mc:Ignorable="d">
    <Grid Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <Pivot>
            <PivotItem>
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Fix Info"/>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
            <PivotItem>
                <PivotItem.Header>
                    <TextBlock Text="Harmonize"/>
                </PivotItem.Header>
                <Grid>
                    <ListView x:Name="LstStanzas"
                              ItemsSource="{Binding SongsViewModel.SongFixViewModel.FixStructure}"
                              ItemsPanel="{StaticResource StanzaItemTemplate}"
                              Grid.Column="2"
                              HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                              ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
                        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
                            </Style>
                        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
                        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
                            <DataTemplate>
                                <ctr:StanzaEditorControl StanzaToEdit="{Binding }" FixStructure="{Binding ElementName=LstStanzas,Path=ItemsSource}"/>
                            </DataTemplate>
                        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
                    </ListView>
                </Grid>
            </PivotItem>
        </Pivot>
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Warnings.Message}" Visibility="{Binding SongsViewModel.SongFixViewModel.Warnings.WarningVisible,Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" Style="{StaticResource WarningMessage}" Grid.Row="1"/>
        <SplitView IsPaneOpen="{Binding SongsViewModel.SongFixViewModel.SyllabeEditorIsOpen}"
                       CompactPaneLength="0"
                       OpenPaneLength="300" PaneBackground="#FF641414" PanePlacement="Right">
            <SplitView.Pane>
                <Grid>
                    <ctr:SyllabeEditorControl SyllabeViewModel="{Binding SongsViewModel.SongFixViewModel.SyllabeEditorModel,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged,Mode=TwoWay}"/>
                </Grid>
            </SplitView.Pane>
        </SplitView>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

And this one named **SongFix.DeviceFamily-Desktop.xaml**

```
<Page
    x:Class="Tablaturas.SongFix"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:local="using:Tablaturas"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    xmlns:cvt="using:Tablaturas.Code"
    xmlns:ctr="using:Tablaturas.Controls"
    xmlns:data="using:Tablaturas.Model"    
    mc:Ignorable="d">
<Grid x:Name="GrdFixEditor" Background="{ThemeResource ApplicationPageBackgroundThemeBrush}">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="4*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <Grid>
    </Grid>
    <ListView x:Name="LstStanzas"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding SongsViewModel.SongFixViewModel.FixStructure}"
                  ItemsPanel="{StaticResource StanzaItemTemplate}"
                  Grid.Column="2"
                  HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch"
                  ScrollViewer.HorizontalScrollBarVisibility="Disabled">
        <ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
            <Style TargetType="ListViewItem">
                <Setter Property="HorizontalContentAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            </Style>
        </ListView.ItemContainerStyle>
        <ListView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <ctr:StanzaEditorControl StanzaToEdit="{Binding }" FixStructure="{Binding ElementName=LstStanzas,Path=ItemsSource}"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ListView.ItemTemplate>
    </ListView>
</Grid>
```

And this is my codebehind

```
namespace Tablaturas.Views
{
    /// <summary>
    /// An empty page that can be used on its own or navigated to within a  Frame.
    /// </summary>
    public sealed partial class SongFix : Page
    {
        public SongFix()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}
```

Now my problem is when I deploy to my phone everything works pretty fine, But when deploy to my pc it throws this error:

```
An exception of type 'System.InvalidCastException' occurred in Tablaturas.exe but was not handled in user code

Additional information: Unable to cast object of type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Grid' to type 'Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView'.
```

If i remove the ListView named **LstStanzas** at **SongFix.xaml**, the app deploy properly at my pc.

Why this error happens into PC deploy if the error is at standard view  ?
What is wrong at standard view, if it runs properly on my phone?

**NOTE:** I'm using Visual Studio Community 2015 with update 2

Could be this a Bug at this version of VS?

**EDIT 1** SongFix.g.cs file

```
namespace Tablaturas.Views
{
partial class SongFix : 
    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.Page, 
    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector,
    global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector2
{
    /// <summary>
    /// Connect()
    /// </summary>
    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 14.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public void Connect(int connectionId, object target)
    {
        switch(connectionId)
        {
        case 1:
            {
                this.LstStanzas = (global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Controls.ListView)(target);
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }
        this._contentLoaded = true;
    }

    [global::System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("Microsoft.Windows.UI.Xaml.Build.Tasks"," 14.0.0.0")]
    [global::System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCodeAttribute()]
    public global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector GetBindingConnector(int connectionId, object target)
    {
        global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IComponentConnector returnValue = null;
        return returnValue;
    }
}
}
```

Comment: `Why this error happens into PC deploy if the error is at standard view ?` There is a special file, named `SongFix.g.cs` (that should be in your `obj` folder) that is automatically generated based on `SongFix.xaml`. It contains, among other things, the mapping between your properties and your controls (that's why, when you put `x:Name` on a control, you can access this control from a property in the code-behind). The same `SongFix.g.cs` is used for SongFix.DeviceFamily-Desktop.xaml` (even though it was generated from `SongFix.xaml`.

Comment: The consequence is that, if you put name a listview `LstStanzas` in `SongFix.xaml`, there will be a `LstStanzas` property in `SongFix.g.cs` with the type `ListView`. If then, in `SongFix.DeviceFamily-Desktop.xaml`, you put the same name to a control of different type (say, `Grid`), you'll have a type mismatch because the `LstStanzas` property in `SongFix.g.cs` will still be of type `ListView`

Comment: That said, I can't explain why you have this issue since `LstStanzas` has the same type in both your XAML files. Maybe you should try to **rebuild** your solution (that's different from a simple build) to force Visual Studio to regenerate your `SongFix.g.cs` file

Comment: Tks. I understand your point, I cleaned my entire solution and rebuild it many many times but the problem persists.

Comment: Oh, I didn't realize there was this `connectionId` thing in UWP (pretty sure it's not there in WPF). Just a hunch, I suspect `connectionId` is incremented following the order of the elements in the XAML. So in your first file, `LstStanzas` has id 1 because it's the first named element. In the second XAML, `GrdFixEditor` is the first named element and gets the id 1, hence the conversion error. If my theory is correct, then removing `x:Name="GrdFixEditor"` (leave the grid, just remove the name) should fix the error

Comment: I'm trying just now removing all x:Name's. But It sounds more like a bug..

Comment: @KooKiz Yep, your theory is ok, it works now. But for me this is a big **BUG**

Comment: Definitely. But that's not the last bug you'll see on UWP, the platform is very young and far from being stable

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect `connectionId` is incremented following the order of the elements in the XAML. So in your first file, `LstStanzas` has id 1 because it's the first named element. In the second XAML, `GrdFixEditor` is the first named element and gets the id 1, hence the conversion error. If my theory is correct, then removing `x:Name="GrdFixEditor"` (leave the grid, just remove the name) should fix the error.

Comment: Tks. you save me a lot of time.